# Elasticsearch don't allow indexing null in date field

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have bellow data to index:

```
array:6 [▼
  "index" => "my_index"
  "type" => "audit_field"
  "id" => "57f36d28a1dfc"
  "parent" => "57f36d289f1b2"
  "routing" => 318
  "body" => array:19 [▼
     "session_id" => 318
     "trans_seq_no" => 13
     "table_seq_no" => 13
     "field_id" => 65
     "field_name" => "id"
     "new_value" => 45
     "old_value" => 45
     "date_type_new_value" => null
     "date_type_old_value" => null
     "time_type_new_value" => null
     "time_type_old_value" => null
 ]
]
```

I have defined mapping myself as bellow

```
array(
    'index' => 'promote_kmp',
    'type' => 'audit_field',
    'body' => [
        'audit_field' => [
            '_source' => [
                'type' => 'string'
            ],
            "_parent" => [
                "type" => "audit_table"
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'session_id'   => array('type' =>  'string'),
                'trans_seq_no' => array('type' =>  'string'),
                'table_seq_no' => array('type' =>  'string'),
                'field_id'     => array('type' =>  'string'),
                'field_name'   => array('type' => 'string'),
                'old_value'    => array(
                    'type' => 'string'
                ),
                'new_value'    => array(
                    'type' => 'string'
                ),
                'date_type_new_value' => array(
                    'type'   => 'date',
                    'format' =>'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||YYYY-MM-dd||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd'
                ),
                'date_type_old_value' => array(
                    'type'   => 'date',
                    'format' =>'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||YYYY-MM-dd||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd'
                ),
                'time_type_new_value' => array(
                    'type'   => 'date',
                    'format' => 'HH:mm:ss'
                ),
                'time_type_old_value' => array(
                    'type'   => 'date',
                    'format' => 'HH:mm:ss'
                )
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

But when i wan to index data with null in date field, elasticsearch shows and exception that can't parse date field value with mapping date format types.
How to solve this, i have also tried with empty, but not working, and give the same message.

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [date_type_new_value]]; nested: 
MapperParsingException[failed to parse date field [], tried both date format 
[YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||YYYY-MM-dd||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd], and timestamp 
number with locale []]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: ""];
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES 7, you have the option of specifying `null_value` as a field property. Null values cannot be searched, however.
See [the manual page on null-values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html) for `null_value` configuration and [the manual page on dates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) for the Date datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why **null** is not working, I can index null value in ES 1.7, also `IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: ""];` indicates blank string and not null value.

If you don't have control over the data, you need to use [ignore_malformed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html) which will not index the date field but index the document normally.

Comment: I have control over data, i have passed null value but that error displayed. I use the same version of elastic.

Comment: That is weird, could you try adding ignore_malformed to mapping?